# Designing e-commerce database

Tags: database-design

Hi I am developing my first e-commerce website and some chalanges in the designing of the database are keeping me from moving forward.The site will be an electronics store that will sell computers , tv's ,telephons  , tablets etc.This is my database diagram so far:

[image]

Now my problem is regarding each product type for example if I have a notebook and a tv this two products will have different properties in the tables.I would think that the notebook will have a column for the CPU , motherboard , video card etc. and the tv columns for type , inches etc.

I have about 38 different product types each having different product descriptions.

The way I tought of it is that for each product type I would create a table but that will result in 38 tables and I do not know if this is the right course of action.

If there is any other way of solving this problem can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this db pic i think help you . But if you have not start your development or you can add these field in the table. this one is complete description

[image: db esign pattern]